# is there a DDL generator out there where you can start with CSV/TSV to create DDL for Cassandra

Tags: ddl, cassandra, automation

Is there a DDL generator out there where you can start with CSV/TSV (or maybe even JSON) to create DDL for Cassandra?

Answer (score -1):

DDL generator for a Cassandra keyspace:

```
DESC KEYSPACE the-Keyspace-name;
```

CSV generator for a Cassandra table:

- [COPY TO](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-to)
- [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkCmd.html).

Comment: I think that it's asked about some code that would use input file to generate Cassandra schema... COPY TO & DSBulk are requiring the existing table